# Integration testing an "modules" appengine app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just refactored our app into different modules.

We also have integration tests which tests.
One of such test was working before, but currently breaks because our tests are only run per module. The test actually tests the inter working between modules.

How can i write a integration test, without the need to spwan up a dev server?

I was using nose-gae, which doesnt really know about modules.

A wokaround would be, to symlink all modules code into one monolithic app, and test that.. hopwever then i wouldnt be testing the dispatch.yaml and code separation that is done in the modules.

Answer (score 0):

What i currently have, is integration tests per module, and no integration tests amongst modules, if you have modules that are clearly separated it shoudnt be a big deal.

However, one of the issues was that the queue.yaml, index.yaml where only defined on application leve, and the app.yaml on module level:

```
/app
  - index.yaml
  - queue.yaml
  /module1
    - app.yaml
```

The test are ran inside the module1 directory.
This caused my module test to fail with an error "UnkownQueueError", since it coudnt find the queue.yaml. I solved this by adding a parameter to the testbed stubs:

```
def reset_gae_stub(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
    self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub(root_path = "../../")
```

The **root_path** parameter tells the taskqueue stub where to find the queue.yaml, which solved the issue for me.